# Google Drive track furthest read page in a PDF, or have selectable text in uploaded Google Books?

Tags: google-drive, pdf, google-books

Is there a way to automatically track the furtherest read page of a PDF in in Google Docs?

I have some large text books and other technical reading I'm working through slowly.  I've uploaded them to Google Books, which keeps track of the last page, which is conveinent, but Google Books does not let me select text from the books (like code examples I want to copy and paste to Python, etc).

Google Docs allows me to select text from these documents, but doesn't remember where I was last time I opened it.  Sometimes the books are very large and it's easy to forget where you were.

Is there a way to solve either of these two problems?  Is there a solution that doesn't include Google Books or Docs (Kindle won't work b/c you can't view documents you've uploaded in the web browser...)